# jQuery binding - how can I bind the result of this Ajax call to the document?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am doing this:

```
jQuery("#country_id").change(function() {
    id = jQuery("#country_id").val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'index.php?option=com_jomdirectory&task=getprovince&format=raw&type=province',
        dataType: "html",
        data: "id=" + id,
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#provincelist').html(data).find('select').addClass("form-control chosen-select").chosen();
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is, this is not binding to the document, so when I try to fire the next ajax call (which retrieves a list of cities),

I essentially have 3 selects:

1) Country - onchange fires ajax call to get provinces (This works and gives me the Province select list)

2) Then when changing Province, it should fire an ajax call for city select

3) City ajax call doesn't fire.

How do I go about binding the result to the document, so that I can fire the next ajax call on change, without fiddling with this piece of code too much?

Thanks,

J

Comment: Binding to the document? What do you mean? This executes successfully when `#country_id` is changed, right?

Comment: it is very unclear what are you trying to achieve

Comment: @PraveenKumar  My next ajax call does not fire, because it is itself the result of an ajax call.  I essentially have 3 selects: 1) Country->Province->City and it works when I change country (the province select shows) but when I change province, nothing happens - the ajax call for city does not fire.

Comment: In your sample, you added a change listener on `country` dropdown only. Did you define similar change listeners for `province` and `city` dropdowns as well ?

Answer (score 1):

> @PraveenKumar My next ajax call does not fire, because it is itself
>   the result of an ajax call. I essentially have 3 selects: 1)
>   Country->Province->City and it works when I change country (the
>   province select shows) but when I change province, nothing happens -
>   the ajax call for city does not fire.

you need to use event delegation for your *province* select.

```
jQuery("#provincelist").on('change', '#province_id', function() {
```

when you are replacing the select using `jQuery('#provincelist').html(data)` you are losing the change event on the *province* select as you are replacing the whole element.

Comment: I doubt that this is a delegation issue. The OP didn't mention whethe he actually defined a change listener on `province` dropdown.

Comment: @Arkantos *but when I change province, nothing happens*

Comment: Nothing happens if the OP forgot to add event listeners :) We need to confirm if that's the case here.

Comment: All the selects have change listeners.  What I did to solve the issue was to create an empty select (with only one option) and then the ajax response replaces the options.  That way I avoid event delegation issues.